# Installing IOTA wallet fails at "npm start"

Tags: iri-node, wallet

I tried to install [IOTA wallet App](https://github.com/iotaledger/wallet) on amazon linux ec2-instance.

> Linux ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx 4.9.77-31.58.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 18 22:15:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

All is fine till last step. It fails at "npm start"

> > iota@2.5.7 start /home/ec2-user/wallet
> >     export NODE_ENV=development || set NODE_ENV=development && electron app/js/main.js
> >     /home/ec2-user/wallet/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> >     npm ERR! file sh
> >     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> >     npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> >     npm ERR! syscall spawn
> >     npm ERR! iota@2.5.7 start: `export NODE_ENV=development || set NODE_ENV=development && electron app/js/main.js`
> >     npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> >     npm ERR! 
> >     npm ERR! Failed at the iota@2.5.7 start script.
> >     npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> >     npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> >     npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-21T06_31_48_556Z-debug.log

**Update**

> sudo yum install libgtk2.0-0
>
> No package libgtk2.0-0 available. Error: Nothing to do

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Can't locate the libgtk-x11-2.0 library. AFAIK it is included in libgtk2, try running `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0`.

Are you sure you need a GUI app on a ec2 instance?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0`
sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: I actually need to connect wallet to a website.

Comment: Using apt instead of apt-get would solve this specific issue. I saw your other question on the site so I'll move the discussion there.

Comment: `[ec2-user@ip-]$ sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0
sudo: apt: command not found
`

Comment: I'm trying with js api also. That's why i posted the other question. I think js approach would be better for a website to interact with wallet data.